# BigDump - UNEXPECTED: Can't set file pointer behind the end of file

Tags: mysql

While trying to start uplaod the 3.9 GB sql file via BigDump there is error

> UNEXPECTED: Can't set file pointer
>   behind the end of file

Dump of database was exported from PHPMyAdmin. File is not corrupted. What is the problem? What are other ways to import such a big database?

Comment: Where are you trying to upload the file using what to what kind of server running what?

Comment: From server on Unix to server on Windows. Both are standard Apache/PHP/MySQL servers.

Comment: Upload how? You mean `LOAD DATA INFILE...` ?

Comment: This could be a filesystem issue - 4GB is a magic limit in some file systems. You are not clearly explaining where the error occurs exactly and what  you are doing, so it's impossible to give any more detail

Comment: @ELi Upliad by using bigdump.php script

Comment: @Pekka FIle is not bigger than 4GB. Error occurs when I click on 'Start Import'. I am using http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.zip

Answer (score 1):

[Bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.zip) uses a `INSERT INTO table VALUES (....)` kind of method.

This is a very slow way of inserting!

Use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/filename.csv' INTO TABLE table1
```

Instead. Note the use of forward slashes even on Windows.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

This is the fastest way possible to insert data into a MySQL table.
It will only work if the input file is on the same server as the MySQL server though.

Answer (score 1):

I get similar error: `I can't seek into .sql`

The reason for this error is, that `BigDump` tries to set pointer at the end of `.sql-File` and then find out its size (using `fseek()` and `fteil()` functions). As `fseek()` is failing when you work with files over `2GB`, you get this error. Solution is to split your SQL-File into chunks of 1,5GB - 2GB size...